# GUI with a button that will start and stop a stopwatch

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a button in a GUI that alternates starting and stopping a stopwatch. This time from the stopwatch will then be put through a function which will output a value that needs to be displayed on the same GUI.

The problem I am having is not being able to correctly make one button do two jobs: start and stop the stopwatch, and print the output of the function on the GUI. If possible the output of the function needs to be displayed above the Start/ Stop button.

```
import time
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
button = Button(window, text="Start/ Stop")

def timer_f():
    while True:
        try:
            start_time = time.time()
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            end_time = time.time()
            x = float(round(end_time - start_time, 2))
            break
    y = str(round(4.905 * x ** 2))
    print("Height= " + y + " meters")

button.config(command=timer_f)  # performs callback of function
button.config(font=("Ink Free", 50, "bold"))  # changes font
button.config(bg="#32a2a8")  # changes background colour of button
button.config(fg="#99a832")
button.config(activebackground="#FF0000")
button.config(activeforeground="#99a832")
button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You CANNOT use `time.sleep` nor an infinite loop in a GUI callback, for ANY of the GUI libraries.  It will freeze your whole UI.  Instead, your callback needs to update its internal state and then use `window.after` to get called back a second later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after.  Note that the button press sets a global "active" flag and then starts the clock ticking.  The ticking stops when the button press clears the "active" flag.

```
import time
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
button = Button(window, text="Start/ Stop")

active = False
start_time = None

def tick():
    if active:
        end_time = time.time()
        x = float(round(end_time - start_time, 2))
        y = str(round(4.905 * x ** 2))
        print("Height= " + y + " meters")
        window.after( 1000, tick )

def timer_f():
    global active
    global start_time
    active = not active
    if active:
        start_time = time.time()
        tick()

button.config(command=timer_f)  # performs callback of function
button.config(font=("Ink Free", 50, "bold"))  # changes font
button.config(bg="#32a2a8")  # changes background colour of button
button.config(fg="#99a832")
button.config(activebackground="#FF0000")
button.config(activeforeground="#99a832")
button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Here's a way to do it without ugly globals, by storing the state in a persistent dictionary:

```
import time
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
button = Button(window, text="Start/ Stop")

state = {'active': False, 'start_time': None}

def tick():
    if state['active']:
        end_time = time.time()
        x = float(round(end_time - state['start_time'], 2))
        y = str(round(4.905 * x ** 2))
        print("Height= " + y + " meters")
        window.after( 1000, tick )

def timer_f():
    state['active'] = not state['active']
    if state['active']:
        state['start_time'] = time.time()
        tick()

button.config(command=timer_f)  # performs callback of function
button.config(font=("Ink Free", 50, "bold"))  # changes font
button.config(bg="#32a2a8")  # changes background colour of button
button.config(fg="#99a832")
button.config(activebackground="#FF0000")
button.config(activeforeground="#99a832")
button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Good answer +1 but you know that all scopes are basically `dict`s in python. So in the last code snippet you moved some of the variables from the `globals()` dictionary into a new `dict` that you named `state`. So whatever is making global variables *ugly*, will also apply to the `dict` you named `state`.

Comment: You are correct, but explicit is better than implicit.  Calling it "state" makes the purpose clear, and eliminates the "global" statements.